# REGEX javascript - find two chars set

Tags: javascript, regex

i've to find the sequence of chars `,.` inside a json file for example: `":0,.0}},{"`, so what is the best fitted regex string for it?

i tried `/(,.){1,}/g` but it doesn't work well.

Comment: `indexOf` is enough, why regex?

Comment: `indexOf` will return only the first occurence of `,.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `.` is a special character.

```
const r = /(?:,\.)+/g
console.log('abc,.,.,.def'.match(r)) //[",.,.,."]
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks a lot man!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the `.`:

```
/,\./g
```